# Why does the answers count below the votes count disappear?

Tags: support, search

I was searching questions one day and

[image: No answer count...]

The answer count for some questions disappeared.

What happened? Did anyone encounter this before?

EDIT: I see that they are answers now. But how come there is a blank space under the vote count?

Comment: Two are answers (A:).

Comment: Why is there a blank space under then?

Comment: And why not? I guess it is just a matter of website design.

Comment: you asking another question after getting the answer?what do you mean by why blank space?look at right side its height is higher than left side.

Comment: I see. Ok then...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It only shows the answer count if it's showing a question. Notice how the ones showing an answer count say "**asked** *date here* by *user here*" and the ones without answer count say "**answered** *date here* by *user here*"

Oh, and the titles are also prefixed with either "Q:" (for Question) or "A:" (for Answer).

[image]